# mysql multi dimensional data

Tags: php, mysql

I need to output multiple rows of selections from my database with something like this. it is outputting the second row but not the first and is returning a warning "Warning: Illegal string offset 'char_name'"

```
$i = 0;
while($array = @mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $row[$i] = $array;
    $char = $row[$i]['char_id'];
    $$char['char_name'] = $row[$i]['char_name'];  /warning is on this line

    echo $char . " " . $$char['char_name'];$i++;
}
```

Comment: add the code : echo "<pre>" . print_r(@mysql_fetch_assoc, true) . "</pre>" right before the $i = 0; and then paste here the result. This will help us find out what is the data structure you like to iterate

Comment: change `echo $char . " " . $$char['char_name'];$i++;` to this `echo $char . " " . $char['char_name'];$i++;`

Comment: change `$$char['char_name'] = $row[$i]['char_name'];` to this `$char['char_name'] = $row[$i]['char_name'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this to

```
$$char['char_name'] = $row[$i]['char_name'];  /warning is on this line
echo $char . " " . $$char['char_name'];
$i++;
```

this

```
$char['char_name'] = $row[$i]['char_name'];  /warning is on this line
echo $char . " " . $char['char_name'];
$i++;
```

Comment: thank you. i was following an example and assumed $$ was making a variable of the variable. it is outputting correctly, and i also removed a fetch_array which caused the first row to not be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Could You rebuild code:

```
$i = 0;
while($array = @mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $row[$i] = $array;
    $char = $row[$i]['char_id'];
    $char_name = $row[$i]['char_name']; 

    echo $char . " " . $char_name;
    $i++;
}
```